# How can I chain vue-resource calls using functions?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, es6-promise, vue-resource

I want to chain two API endpoints (login and then get user). I am aware that you can chain vue-resource calls using `.then`, as in the following example, which works well:

```
function login (creds) {
  // First, call login endpoint
  this.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, creds).then(response => {
    // Handle login
    return userId
  }, response => {
    // Handle errors
  }).then((userId)=> {
    // Then, chain the get user endpoint
    this.$http.get(USER_URL + userId).then(response => {
      // Handle get user
      // Finally, redirect to user dashboard
    }, response => {
      // Handle errors
    })
  })
}
```

The problem is that I want to create a separate function for the get user endpoint for reusability and separation of concerns. When I create it, however, it is not guaranteed that the `getUser` function will be completed before I redirect to the user dashboard at the very end (and I don't want to redirect inside `getUser`).

```
function getUser (userId) {
  this.$http.get(USER_URL + userId).then(response => {
    // Handle get user
  }, response => {
    // Handle errors
  })
}

function login (creds) {
  // First, call login endpoint
  this.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, creds).then(response => {
    // Handle login
    return userId
  }, response => {
    // Handle errors
  }).then((userId)=> {
    getUser(userId)  // Function not guaranteed to finish before proceeding
    // Should only proceed if getUser() is completed
    // Finally, redirect to user dashboard
  })
}
```

In the second example, the `getUser` function is never completed on time before the user is redirected to the dashboard, which is causing some inconsistencies in the login process. I believe I can use JS promises, though I am unsure of how the implementation would be in this case.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the promises from all your functions.

Comment: @Bergi So if I do `return this.$http.get...` in the `getUser` function, how can I make sure it finished in the `login` function?

Comment: I meant *all* of them, including callback functions - e.g. `return getUser(userId);`. Then you can simply chain another `.then(redirectToDashboard)` to the end of your chain (either inside `login`, or even after the `login()` call).